# Magento 1.9x How to increase shipping costs when mutiple products are ordered?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I'm implenting a shipping costs rate into our webshop, however, i'm looking for a way that when customers buy more products at once, the shipping costs increase, so in short:

Customers buy 1-4 laptops; shipping is 5$.

Customers buy 5-10 of the same laptops; shipping becomes 10$

Is there a way to implent this in our magento webshop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i recommend http://webshopapps.com/row/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html this free extension this will complete your requirement. Here you can set shipping charges according to # of Items vs. Destination.

Comment: I'll check it out right now, and get back to you if it works, Thanks for helping me so quickly :)

Comment: I've downloaded the extension, but i don't see the option where i can put in the increase of shipping costs when customers buy more products at once

Comment: have you downloaded the csv provided by extension.

Comment: Nope, i haven't received any csv file

Comment: change Current Configuration Scope to website and then under  **shipping method -> Webshopapps Matrix Rates ->** you will get a **export button** which will provide you csv.

Comment: alright, i exported it and received a .csv file,  i see a few options,  so can i set in #of items From, #of items to, shipping price  that 1-4 products will be 9$  and 5-10 products the price will be 16$ ?

Comment: correct and import this csv into the system with same process. you will be receiving the shipping rates on checkout page and shopping cart page hope this will help you :).

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by correct the csv?

Comment: i mean to say you did the correct process go ahead and import the csv after inserting the proper values

Comment: Thank you!  i read it wrong, haha.  I will insert the proper values, and then import the file,

Comment: After i inserted the values and wanted to import it,  i got this error:   An error occurred while saving this configuration: Invalid Matrix Rates File Format

Comment: have you made some changes to file format ? it should be csv just put your values save it and import it.

Comment: Yes, it's still csv, maybe i insert the values wrong, is there someway for you to check that?  Like via a website like pastebin, or would it be helpful to just upload a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the screenshot.[image]

Refer the above image while making entry in the csv of matrix rate.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot, i will make the file according the screenshot and upload it and see if it works, sorry for late reply, i am just now back to my computer, thank you i will keep you updated if it works

Comment: Hello,  i got error: An error occurred while saving this configuration: Invalid Matrix Rates File Format       i made file according your screenshot   i saved file to .csv    here is my screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/5i4VJUq.png

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweKwHQ_asV2b2loRTZCRFFxVEk/view?usp=sharing  download this file and use this one. let me know if you still have an issue or not.

Comment: I have downloaded the file and will try this one on the website,  i will keep you updated on if it works, thank you :)

Comment: It works absolutely perfect, thank you!  One question though,  is it possible to assign this method to a group of products? As in laptops only,  and the rest of the products like cables and monitor stands just have a default shipping charge?

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer then you can accept it and up vote it and as far as your question is concern regarding group of product, in default extension it is not possible but you can customize it as per your need, for this you have  to make some changes in code of this extension.

Comment: Ah, i see. i will extend that to another day, thank you so much for your help, i will vote and accept your answer and i wish you a great day!